# ROS Answers SE migration: Bullet stack

Tags: ros, bullet, include, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to use some elements of bullet library in my code.
In particular I want to convert from quaternions to roll,pitch and yaw.
I've seen that i can do:

```
btQuaternion q;
double roll, pitch, yaw;
tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->pose.pose.orientation, q);
btMatrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

But I don't know how to include the bullet library in my code.
Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51465/bullet-stack/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where did you see that code? Bullet's math library has been forked and is part of TF since ROS Fuerte so the above code should not work. I suggest you use the TF library and the data types tf::Quaternion and bt::Matrix3x3.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-07**:
i used this code:  tf::Pose pose;
tf::poseMsgToTF(msg->pose.pose, pose);
theta_r = tf::getYaw(pose.getRotation());